# How to define a macro that uses image width and height to define a variable for later use

Tags: macros, graphics, subfloats, calculations

Ok, the title might be a bit cryptic and my question is a bit lengthy, so please bear with me.

What I want to do is: 
I have two images with different aspect ratios that I want to place next to each other using `subfloat`. Together both images should fill the `\textwidth` and on the other hand have the same height. Also a gap between both images should be allowed. Analytically there is only one physical height (say `\finalheight`) for both images, such that all conditions are fullfilled:

```
\finalheight = (\textwidth - gap_width) / (width_im_1/height_im_1 + width_im_2/height_im_2)
```

where the annotations `_im_1` and `_im_2` refer to the first and the second image, respectively. Once calculated the `\finalheight` can then used in the figure command as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{fistimage}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{secondimage}}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}
```

I have already a code that works within the body of the document i.e.:

```
\newlength\firstheight
\newlength\firstwidth
\newlength\firstratio
\newlength\secondheight
\newlength\secondwidth
\newlength\secondratio
\newlength\gapspace
\newlength\finalheight
\newlength\effwidth
\newlength\sumratio

\def\first{\includegraphics{pathToFirstImage}}
\setlength{\firstheight}{\heightof{\first}}
\setlength{\firstwidth}{\widthof{\first}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstratio}{\firstwidth/\firstheight}

\def\second{\includegraphics{pathToSecondImage}}
\setlength{\secondheight}{\heightof{\second}}
\setlength{\secondwidth}{\widthof{\second}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\secondratio}{\secondwidth/\secondheight}

\setlength{\gapspace}{0.5cm}

\setlength{\effwidth}{\textwidth-\gapspace}
\setlength{\sumratio}{\firstratio+\secondratio}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\finalheight}{\effwidth/\sumratio}
```

However, I now tried to package the above code as a macro:

```
\newcommand{\calcoptimalheight}{3}[0.5cm]{
...
 }
```

with only these lines modified:

```
\def\first{\includegraphics{#2}}
\def\second{\includegraphics{#3}}
\setlength{\gapspace}{#1}  .
```

This however results in an

```
"! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)"
```

error when trying to evaluate

```
\def\first{\includegraphics{#2}}  .
```

**Now finally my question:** Is there some reason that `\includegraphics` may not be used this way in a macro. If not is the approach altogether wrong to use a macro to set a variable as explained above. I've been using LaTeX for quite some time, but I never messed too much with macros or custom variables myself and could not find help for this issue searching the web.

**Edit**:

Inculding the suggestions from the answer below the code works, the problem was the wrong syntax in the `\newcommand` definition: `{3}` instead of `[3]`. Unfortunately, the error message sent me on the wrong path, I should have seen that. After inculsion of the improvemts from [How to preserve lenghts to use with \includegraphics scaling, when calculating them with pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122526/how-to-preserve-lenghts-to-use-with-includegraphics-scaling-when-calculating-t) also the error message is solved. In case it is useful for somebody I add an minimal working example including the solutions from the answers to this and the other question:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, paper=A4]{scrbook}
%
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
%
\newcommand{\optimalheight}[3][0.5cm]{%
  \newlength\firstheight%
  \newlength\firstwidth%
  \newlength\secondheight%
  \newlength\secondwidth%
  \newlength\effwidth%
  \newlength\finalheight%
  \def\firstim{\includegraphics{<imageA>}}%
  \def\secondim{\includegraphics{<imageB>}}%
  \setlength{\firstheight}{\heightof{\firstim}}%
  \setlength{\firstwidth}{\widthof{\firstim}}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\firstratio}{\firstwidth/\firstheight}%
  \setlength{\secondheight}{\heightof{\secondim}}%
  \setlength{\secondwidth}{\widthof{\secondim}}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondratio}{\secondwidth/\secondheight}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\gapspace}{0.5cm}%
  \pgfmathsetlength{\effwidth}{\textwidth-\gapspace}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sumratio}{\firstratio+\secondratio}%
  \pgfmathsetlength{\finalheight}{\effwidth/\sumratio}% 
 }
%   
\newcommand{\subfloatsSameheight}[3][0.5cm]{%
  \optimalheight{#2}{#3}%
  \subfloat[a)]{\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{#2}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[b)]{\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{#3}}%
}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}[]
 \begin{centering}
   \subfloatsSameheight{<imageA>}{<imageB>}
   \caption[]{}
   \label{}
 \end{centering}
\end{figure} 
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Analytically, W1 = (k2/(k1+k2)) \textwidth, where k1 and k2 are the image aspect ratios (k=height/width) and W1 is width of image 1.  Obviously W2=\textwidth-W1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please always show a complete document that generates the problem. You show some code and you show an error message, but not the code that generates the error.

TeX is a macro expansion language you can almost always put any sequence of commands in a macro and they work the same way. Here, where no catcode/verbatim trickery is used it is certainly possible.

```
\def\first{\includegraphics{#2}}
\def\first{\includegraphics{#3}}
\setlength{\gapspace}{#1}
```

That middle line should presumably be defining `\second`.

```
\setlength{\effwidth}{\textwidth-\gapspace}
```

would normally be a synax error but as you say it works, presumably you have loaded `calc` package? (Again it is much easier if you show a complete document with all relevant packages)

The syntax for `\newcommand` that you show is incorrect

```
\newcommand{\calcoptimalheight}{3}[0.5cm]{
```

Is not a syntax error but `3` is the entire body of the definition, you want

```
\newcommand{\calcoptimalheight}[3][0.5cm]{%
```

You probably want to add `%` at the end of every line as well.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I'll keep your advice in mind,next time I'll provide a more complete example. Unfortunaltely, your proposed modifications do not change the outcome. I'll prepare a minimal, updated example and add it to the original question.

Comment: Actually I have been mistaken, producing the minimal example I found that the code runs fine, altough the error message persists.