# How to preserve lenghts to use with \includegraphics scaling, when calculating them with pgf

Tags: macros, graphics, calculations, lengths, pgfmath

This question is related to my earlier question here:
[How to define a macro that uses image width and height to define a variable for later use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122299/how-to-define-a-macro-that-uses-image-width-and-height-to-define-a-variable-for) .
There you can find a full MWE of the problematic code. Which I skip here for sake of brevity.

I use a mixture of `\newlength`, `\setlength` and `\pgfmathsetmacro` to calculate the optimal height for two figures I want to plot. The code works fine and the resulting images are displayed correclty. **However**, I get the error message:

```
ERROR: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

when using the calculated height (here `\finalheight`) for:

```
\includegraphics[height=\finalheight] .
```

My guess is that using e.g.

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\finalheight}{\effwidth/\sumratio} ,
```

I change a length that has a physical unit, to a mere number. Is that right? However I had a problem using `\setlength` to calculate ratios, which is why I started to use `\pgfmathsetmacro` in the first place. Does someone know a clean way to perform the calculation below such that the results `\finalheight` has a unit?

```
\newlength\firstheight%
\newlength\firstwidth%
\newlength\secondheight%
\newlength\secondwidth%
\def\firstim{\includegraphics{pathToImage}}%
\def\secondim{\includegraphics{pathToImage}}%
\setlength{\firstheight}{\heightof{\firstim}}%
\setlength{\firstwidth}{\widthof{\firstim}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstratio}{\firstwidth/\firstheight}%
\setlength{\secondheight}{\heightof{\secondim}}%
\setlength{\secondwidth}{\widthof{\secondim}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\secondratio}{\secondwidth/\secondheight}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gapspace}{0.5cm}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\effwidth}{\textwidth-\gapspace}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\sumratio}{\firstratio+\secondratio}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\finalheight}{\effwidth/\sumratio}%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up macro and length assignments. `\pgfmathsetmacro` results in a numeric output which is void of any unit of measure. If you insist on using `\pgfmathsetmacro`, then you need to use

```
\includegraphics[height=\finalheight pt]{<image>}
```

Alternatively, [`pgfmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) provides `\pgfmathsetlength` which preserves the dimension component in the calculation. However, this requires you to pre-define additional lengths, as needed. Try the following:

```
\newlength\firstheight%
\newlength\firstwidth%
\newlength\secondheight%
\newlength\secondwidth%
\newlength\effwidth% <--- Added
\newlength\finalheight% <--- Added
\def\firstim{\includegraphics{<imageA>}}%
\def\secondim{\includegraphics{<imageB>}}%
\setlength{\firstheight}{\heightof{\firstim}}%
\setlength{\firstwidth}{\widthof{\firstim}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstratio}{\firstwidth/\firstheight}%
\setlength{\secondheight}{\heightof{\secondim}}%
\setlength{\secondwidth}{\widthof{\secondim}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\secondratio}{\secondwidth/\secondheight}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gapspace}{0.5cm}%
\pgfmathsetlength{\effwidth}{\textwidth-\gapspace}% <--- Changed
\pgfmathsetmacro{\sumratio}{\firstratio+\secondratio}%
\pgfmathsetlength{\finalheight}{\effwidth/\sumratio}% <--- Changed
```

Comment: Thanks that was fast. Both methods work. I've updated the MWE in the other question to include the changes.

Comment: There is also `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` which sets a macro but also includes the unit `pt`.